# Is galvanized pipe safe for use as a bathroom faucet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

Since the Food and Drug Association (FDA) has approved the use of galvanized steel for food preparation and conveyance for all applications with the exception of foods that have a high acid content, such as tomatoes, oranges, limes, and other fruits. The acid content in these foods will attack the zinc coating and cause accelerated corrosion.
Is there any reason not to use galvanized pipe?

I am re-imaging an old antique buffet into a bathroom vanity. I am using a galvanized bucket for the sink and want to use silver pipe for the faucet, with old fashioned ceramic hot and cold knobs. This will be used daily for washing and teeth brushing. What I need know is will this be safe for human use? Copper will be used underneath the sink area, but I want silver/galvanized for the faucet.
Pic is what I would like to use, I just need to know if it's chemically safe. Thank You.

[image]

Comment: "Safe" is a continuum. It's largely a matter of opinion and risk tolerance. A quick search yields [a plethora of articles on the subject](https://www.google.com/search?q=galvanized+pipe+health+concerns), so I'm not sure it's worth us rewriting that here.

Comment: Have you done any research yourself? Looks like this should be reasonably simple to answer with a quick `<search engine of choice>` search.

Comment: FYI, you might want to get some “silver galvanizing paint” and coat the exposed threads when the pipe is threaded the zinc coating is cut off and it will rust unless covered.

Comment: Yes galvanized piping is fine but you should get a mixing valve or else you could run into trouble trying to set a comfortable water temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Since galvanized pipe was used for close to 100 years as water supply lines yes it is fine to use in your sink.
Galvanized fell out of favor in the 70’s because it is harder to install but I know a couple of contractors that still use it today for the main into the house because it is tough.

You do want to use dielectric unions for your connection from the galvanized to the copper if you don’t galvanic action will corrode the pipe at the junction very quickly in some cases less than a year in others 3+ it depends on the water.

For those that point to the pipe building up on the inside that takes decades in my experience.  And those that talk about lead in the pipe but use brass and stainless just don’t have a clue that unless the brass is rated for potable water it will contain more lead and even brass that is rated for potable water has lead , just an approved amount. Stainless now we deal with chromium, plastic do we even know some haven’t been in use for that long.
There was a time when lead was used for both pipe and solder those days ended back in the 70’s for solder and much earlier for pipe because lead leaks.

I don’t know of any method of transporting water that California prop 65 doesn't require a warning and I don’t even live there any more but everything has the risk warnings.

.

Comment: Prop 65 warnings now appear on nearly everything.  The warning has become meaningless.

Comment: I absolutely agree!

Comment: Sadly, @jwh20, because it's cheaper to print the useless warning on everything than it is to stock & ship items for CA and for ROW. Just like there used to be "California cars" and "everywhere else" cars. Because of costs & practicalities, CA now gets to set defacto standards for the whole country. `</rant>`

Comment: @jwh20 Clearly the label's intent is to warn you of the chemicals in the sticker's adhesive layer.